# zsh: keep slash before parenthesis

Tags: echo, special-characters, zsh

I need to cache a string from a file to do a grep search later. That string has a slash before a parenthesis. After I grab the string and echo it in the shell, it behaves the way I expect; but in my script it drops the slash off.

There's a lot of text below, but the part of the string that matters is "(remainingTime)"

Line in file:

```
"session_will_expire_message" = "User session will expire in \(remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction.";
```

Shell Command (working as expected):

```
% line="\"User session will expire in \(remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction.\";"
% echo $line
"User session will expire in \(remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction.";
% echo -E - $line
"User session will expire in \(remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction.";
% val="$(echo -E - $line | cut -d";" -f1 | cut -d"=" -f2-)"
% echo $val
"User session will expire in \(remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction."
% echo -E - "${val}"
"User session will expire in \(remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction."
```

Script (NOT working as expected):

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $(echo $line | grep -c "=") -gt 0 ]]; then
        key="$(echo $line | cut -d";" -f1 | cut -d"=" -f1 | tr -d " ")"
        val="$(echo -E - $line | cut -d";" -f1 | cut -d"=" -f2-)"
/* !!--> */ [[ $IS_VERBOSE == "TRUE" ]] && echo "key: $key" && echo -E - "value: ${val}"                
/* !!--> */ [[ $key != "" && "${val}" != "" ]] && LOCALIZED_PAIR[$key]="${val}"
    fi
done < $LOCALIZED_DICT   # <-- This is an URI for .strings file
```

The lines marked with "!! -->" are outputting to shell and to a file without the slash...

> key: "session_will_expire_message"
>
> value:  "User session will expire in (remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction."

**Why is my script working differently, and how can I fix it?**

**EDIT:**

It seems the slash is getting stripped out by the while loop:

```
% while read l; do echo $l; done < ~/Desktop/tmpOutput 
"User session will expire in (remainingTime). Please sign in again to avoid expiration in the middle of the transaction.";
```

**If the slashes are being split when the while loop reads the line, is there a way to avoid that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary extra processes. Aside from that, though, use the `-r` option to prevent `read` from processing any backslashes in the input.

```
while IFS== read -r key val; do
    [[ -z $key || -z $val ]] && continue
    if [[ $IS_VERBOSE == TRUE ]]; then
        print -r "key: $key"
        print -r "value: $val"
    fi
    LOCALIZED_PAIR[$key]=$val
done < "$LOCALIZED_DICT"
```

Comment: I like the guard statement logic btw, although I'd probably set it after the echo

Comment: Tried using that in my script. The value fails a lot because of the stripped formatting, but that's to be expected. Unfortunately, this code has the same issue with that line

Comment: I forgot the key option.

Comment: The slash is still getting stripped out when I add the "-r" option. I think that's the only change.

Comment: The slash is still there (check with `declare -p val` or `echo "$val"`); `print` itself (TIL) is consuming it. It takes the `-r` option to prevent that.